# Positioning of items with vertical text - Hover / Absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, css-position

Hi Ive to create a list with vertical list elements and I want them to scale and overlap other items in the list when hovered over without making other items to move. I've made some progress please see

http://jsfiddle.net/saqibmbhatti/P74GG/6/

```
<ul>

  <li>
    <div class="placeholder">
      <span class="rotated-text">Item - 1</span>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="placeholder">
      <span class="rotated-text">Item - 2</span>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="placeholder">
      <span class="rotated-text">Item - 3 is long</span>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="placeholder">
      <span class="rotated-text">Item - 4 is longer</span>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

I still can't figure out why the items jump downwards when one of the items is hovered.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards,
S.

Comment: The absolute positioning is forcing the elements downward in ul li:hover.  Did you try relative positioning?  What exact functionality are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

add `vertical-align: top` to your li's

```
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height:150px;
    line-height:35px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: arial;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

## jsFiddle